# BiPredicate analogue in C#

Tags: java, c#, java-stream

I am Java Engineer and need to write the same solution from Java to C#.
Now I have to rewrite this sample:

```
private static final BiPredicate<SomeObject, String> predicate = 
    (someObject, someId) -> {
        if (someId.startsWith("someText")) {
            // some logic
            return booleanResult;
        }
        return anotherBooleanResult;
    };
```

BiPredicate is a functional interface that has a method which accepts two objects and returns boolean result depending on implementation and the main advantage of it over the regular method is that it could be used in Java Stream as follows:

```
someList.stream().filter(someObject => predicate.test(someObject, someId));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `Func` in C#

```
Func<SomeObject, string, bool> predicate = (someObject, someId) =>
{
  if (someId.StartsWith("someText"))
  {
      // some logic
      return booleanResult;
  }
  return anotherBooleanResult;
};
```

The last generic argument is the return type, all other arguments are the types of parameters passed to the method.
This also works with more than 2 arguments.